# Usage of data() in Jquery Scrolly.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I am trying to make a parallax plugin for myself and found a simple parallax plugin online called scroll.js :

it has a few confusing lines of code though, even multiple checks to the doc's don't help. The jQuery documentation says that the data method in jQuery accepts a `key : Value` pair and even though a lot of code in the plugin is passed through reference, I don't see a key:value pair formation.

A Google search does slightly better and I had an overall better understanding of the `data` method after a search on Google, however that still did't help me in the context of using the `data` method in jQuery plugins, so here's my difficulty.

the snippet of code that I did't understand is :

```
 $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };
```

the entire plugin source code can be found here (don't worry ! its just under 100 lines ! not a huge plugin) . [Plugin on Git](https://github.com/Victa/scrolly/blob/master/jquery.scrolly.js)

Now my difficulty with the above piece of code is, all the examples of the data method I have seen so far in tutorial etc, the usage of the `data` method in the real world plugin is rather different. What is the author really using the data function here for?

Apart from the line:

```
return this.each(function () {
```

all other lines of code, i don't totally confidently understand them. what are they doing?

eg. what is the below line doing ?

```
if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
```

checking if 'plugin_' + pluginName has an properties initailized as an object literal ?? is my assumption correct?

what if the condition returns true? :

```
 $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
```

the above line of code is executed, but what is it doing again ??

I see the data method being used again, the keyword this is used to point to the current element, 'plugin_' + pluginname (i guess this specifies that "this" should point 'plugin_' + pluginname??? ) and lastly a new instance is created.

My understanding of Jquery is not great, I have made an attempt to guess or rather interpret what's happening in this small snippet of code. Sorry if my interpretation is way off the mark.

If somebody could really come along and tell me whats really happening, that would be great.

An important reason for me asking this question is because i have seen similar snippets of code in a lot of contemporary Jquery plugins .

Comment: jQuery has two different `data` methods.  [This one](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/), as used in the above code, and [this one](http://api.jquery.com/data/) which is probably the one you're thinking of.  They both essentially do the same, but the first one requires an element (the `this` in this code) to be passed as the first parameter.

Comment: @JamesThorpe i saw that while googling , but since u specifically pointed it out , i'll go google more about the difference .

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i have another question :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499842/scrolly-js-initializing-code-a-bit-confusing . if ur free, it would be great if you could answer that . :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie , I'll save ur answer in an archive and mark it as answered .  but i'am still learning Jquery , so can't say , i totally understand it , but thats how u learn i guess :) .

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins store the class (function) instance as data on the DOM element, so it can be easily found later to provide the correct "this" reference for method calls. The `data(key, value)` call stores raw objects into a name/value cache (not necessarily on the element itself). A `data(key)` call retrieves the object associated with that key.

The version of `data` used is the *static* jQuery `data` method, so "this" (the element) is provided as a parameter. It is equivalent to the element based version of `data` like this: `$(this).data(key, value)`.

The following line checks if the type of object (that plug-in-name/key value) object already exists before creating a new instance. If it already has that plugin it will not create one again (hence the if). Usually if it exists, the plugin will take any new options passed and change its settings, but your example plugin does not do that:

```
if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
```

The following line stores a new instance of the class (e.g. the actual plugin instance):

```
$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
```

The `new Plugin( this, options )` part calls the class constructor (main function) with a reference to the DOM element, and the options object provided to the plugin call.

```
function Plugin( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.$element = $(this.element);

    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;

    this.init();
}
```

Inside the constructor it will store the element reference, extend a default set of option values with the options passed, then initialize the plugin (register event handlers etc to do the real work).

Comment: I'll accept your answer only once i understand that code snippet , so gimme some time , your answer might solve some of my difficulty , but i might come up with some new ones . Thanks .

Comment: @Tenali_raman: Feel free to ask for specific details. I have written my own base plugin class, as well as over 2 dozen jQuery plugins, so should be able to clarify it for you :)

Comment: thats great :) I'll surely have some more questions for u then .