# scrolly.js initializing code , a bit confusing

Tags: jquery, filtering

I was going through the source code of a simple parallax plugin, and came across a piece of code that seems to be very very familiar or rather a pattern across a lot of other plugins ,

The plugin in concern is :

[Scrolly.js](https://github.com/Victa/scrolly/blob/master/jquery.scrolly.js#L55)

and the bit of code thats confusing is :

```
  $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
```

somehow i am not able to come to terms with what that piece of code.

on a little enquiry, i was able to demystify the 1st line :

```
 $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
```

what the above line does is for example:

assuming pluginName = "killTheRabbit", then it is the same as

```
 $.fn.killTheRabbit = function ( options ) {
```

But they can call it many times with different values for  pluginName

i got the following answer from a JQuery forum .

i ran a few debugging console.log statements and noticed that it is this function that executes 1st when a plugin is called . perticularly i don't understand the below 2 lines at all .

```
if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
```

i know its the data function in Jquery at play here and the data function can be used to associate data with any element in the DOM , which can be later accessed (Sorry if i'am wrong ! thats the best i could understand from the doc's).

I am particularly asking this question because i see that snippet of code in a lot of Jquery plugins.

If you choose to answer this question :

Please be as elaborate as possible and try explaining it in simple english and  less Jquery terms as possible .

also i have a supplementary question : is there anyway i can write a test case that will show me exactly what this function is doing ?? and under what circumstances the if condition fails and passes ?? (You can really choose not to answer this ! thats fine . ).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie you last answer was quite insightful , unfortunatly , my newbie brain still has difficulty processing the complexities of Jquery, if you have some time, could you try, answering this question of mine , which is very close to what i initially asked , except a bit more simplified :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines:

```
    if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
    }
```

are the same as this pseudo code:

```
  if not elementData["key"] then
       elementData["key"] = new object
  end if
```

Translated into English as:

"If I have not already stored a plugin object on my element, *using the name of the plugin as the key*, *then* create an instance of my plugin and store that instance on my element, using the name of the plugin as the key".

This part simply creates a JavaScript object instance, passing a couple of useful parameters (Javascript objects are a type of function):

```
new Plugin( this, options )
```

Test case for the supplementary question (just call it twice on the same element):

```
// First time will go into the `if` and create the object
$('#elementId').killTheRabbit();

// Call it again and it will not create the object (as you already have that plugin on the element)
$('#elementId').killTheRabbit();
```